# Spring outer transaction failure roll back inner transaction

Tags: spring, transactional

I have the following code using Spring @Transactional annotation.

```
//in A.java
Class A {
    @Transactional(propagation=propagation.???)
    public void aMethod() {
        B b = new B();
        b.bMethod(); // success and committed
        aPrivateMethod(); // failure
    }

    private void aPrivateMethod() { //something }
}

//in B.java
Class B {
    @Transactional(propagation=propagation.???)
    public void bMethod() { //something }
}
```

The behavior I expect of A.aMethod() is:

> If b.bMethod() succeeds and has committed but aPrivateMethod() fails,
>   then A.aMethod() is rolled back including b.bMethod().

How can I set the @Transactional propagation parameters to achieve this?

Comment: You are looking for savepoints as `rollback to savepoint` you can rollback before methodb. JPA does not support them.

Comment: You need `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)` on both `A` and `B`. However, since `Propagation.REQUIRED` is the default value for the `propagation` attribute of `@Transactional`, simply `@Transactional` will also do. `Propagation.REQUIRED` indicates that a transaction is required, meaning, if one is already in progress, the code should be executed within that transaction, and if one doesn't, a new one should be created. `A` will start the transaction and `B` will join it. `B` will commit only after `A` has finished, not before.

Comment: B must have `REQUIRES_NEW` as the propagation level. This will make it work in a new separate transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the conclusion.

**Example 1**

```
// A.java
class A {
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void aMethod() {
        B b = new B();
        try {
            b.bMethod("111", false); // bMethod() is NOT rolled back, record of "111" has been created
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Do nothing, let it go
        }
        b.bMethod("222", true); // record of "222" has been created
    }

    // The annotation below is ignored
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void bMethod(String id, bool success) {
        createRecordInDB(id);
        if (!success) {
            throw new Exception("Throw exception explicitly!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
// A.java
class A {
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void aMethod() {
        B b = new B();
        b.bMethod("111", true); // record of "111" has been rolled back and NOT created
        b.bMethod("222", true); // record of "222" has been rolled back and NOT created
        createRecordInDB("333"); // record of "333" has been rolled back and NOT created
        throw new Exception("Throw exception explicitly!");
    }

    // The annotation below is ignored
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void bMethod(String id, bool success) {
        createRecordInDB(id);
        if (!success) {
            throw new Exception("Throw exception explicitly!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 3**

```
// A.java
class A {
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void aMethod() {
        B b = new B();
        try {
            b.bMethod("111", false); // bMethod() has been rolled back, record of "111" has NOT been created
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Do nothing, let it go
        }
        b.bMethod("222", true); // record of "222" has been created
    }
}

// B.java
class B {
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void bMethod(String id, bool success) {
        createRecordInDB(id);
        if (!success) {
            throw new Exception("Throw exception explicitly!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 4**

```
// A.java
class A {
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void aMethod() {
        B b = new B();
        b.bMethod("111", true); // record of "111" has been created
        b.bMethod("222", true); // record of "222" has been created
        createRecordInDB("333"); // record of "333" has been rolled back and NOT created
        throw new Exception("Throw exception explicitly!");
    }
}

// B.java
class B {
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void bMethod(String id, bool success) {
        createRecordInDB(id);
        if (!success) {
            throw new Exception("Throw exception explicitly!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is contrary to what has been asked in the question: *aPrivateMethod() fails, then A.aMethod() is rolled back **including b.bMethod()***. With this answer, *aPrivateMethod() fails, then A.aMethod() is rolled back **but not b.bMethod()***, because `bMethod` starts a new transaction.

Comment: Yep and bMethod propagation must be requires.

Answer (score 0):

All posted examples will open up a new transaction context irrespective of any outer transactions. Hence REQUIRES_NEW will only work within its transactional block and rollback changes within this scope only.
You just need to provide:

```
Class A {
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void aMethod() {
        B b = new B();
        b.bMethod(); // success and committed
        aPrivateMethod(); // failure
    }

    private void aPrivateMethod() { //something }
}
```

Comment: is this a comment to the other answer?